# WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK not working on Android 13

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, wifimanager, android-13

**Background**

We developed an enterprise app using Android Studio that runs in the foreground that restricts user access to any standard android functionality like changing the wi-fi connection etc.

We use the code below to allow the users to change the Wi-Fi connection:

```java
startActivity(new Intent(WifiManager.ACTION_PICK_WIFI_NETWORK));
```

We also use the following permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```html
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
```

**Issue**

Using this method on Android 9 & 10 worked fine for years but now it stopped working with the release of Android 13.

We see the Wi-Fi selection screen appear but it does not list any hotspots not even the one the Android device is connected to.

What are we missing? I am thinking it is some new undocumented permission that we need to add.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!